How to change the severity level in SpotBug (Jenkins)?
I'm using Jenkins with a maven spotbug plugin and certains "bugs" are listed as low, for example some MALICIOUS_CODE category and I found that classification too gentle.. Maybe it being "Normal" or "High" would be more appropriate.
SO is there a way to change the level of severity for certain type of categories of bugs in the files or via Jenkins? I couldn't find anything usefull as of now.
Thx!
I saw that there's a threshold option in : " spotbugs/src/main/java/edu/umd/cs/findbugs
/TextUICommandLine.java" but I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for ...
